# Is there a way in Big query to execute dynamic queries something like 'EXEC' in sql server?

Tags: dynamic, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I have a table with over 200 column names which are created with a temporary name like - custColum1 -custColum200.

I have a mapping table which contains a list of custColum1-custColumn200 to which name it has to be mapped with. For example

```
Table1(custColum1,custColum2) 
Mappingtable(tempColumnName,RealColumnName) 
data in mapping table be like 
(custColum1,Role_number)
(custColum2,Person_name)
```

I need to change table 1 to Table1(Role_number,Person_name). 
Note: I cannot create table1 with this name sincew I don't know which column would be mapped.

Was thinking if We could do something like creating a dynamic query and execute as shown below

```
SET @Sql = 'ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME RENAME Column columnName'
           print  (@Sql)
           EXEC (@Sql)
```

Is there a way to do this in BigQuery? Any ideas will be great

Comment: Bigquery doesn't support dynamic sql. See this answer for some options which might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/54907722/1031958

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let’s assume simplified example as below

Table1
[image]

Mappingtable
[image]

The way I would approach your use case **manually** would be as below
First, assume we know in advance all mappings and we can assemble needed list manually and use it as below

```
#standardSQL
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project.dataset.Table1` AS 
SELECT NULL AS Role_number, NULL AS Person_name  -- this line to be generated
  FROM (SELECT 1) WHERE FALSE UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.Table1`
```

Now, we need to “figure out” how to generate below line from the above query

```
'SELECT NULL AS Role_number, NULL AS Person_name'
```

This can be done by running below query

```
#standardSQL
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT', STRING_AGG(CONCAT(' NULL AS ', RealColumnName) ORDER BY pos)) select_statement
FROM (
  SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t) AS cols FROM `project.dataset.Table1` t LIMIT 1
), UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(cols, r'"(.*?)":')) col WITH OFFSET AS pos
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.Mappingtable` ON tempColumnName = col
```

This will produce exactly string we need

```
'SELECT NULL AS Role_number, NULL AS Person_name'
```

So, now the question is how to add above dynamically built fragment into query that we are interested in!
Unfortunately, it is not doable as a one query purely within the BigQuery, but **super simple** task to accomplish in ANY [client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) or tool of your choice

I can demonstrate how easily this can be done by non-technical user with the Tool of my choice – Magnus (part of [Potens.io](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/potens-io/potensio) – Suite of tools for BigQuery)

Below is snapshot of Magnus Workflow with just two BigQuery Tasks, which reproduce exactly above steps

[image]

As you can see here:

In first Task we generate the statement with expected mapped Column names and assign result to parameter called `var_columns_list` (after workflow execution it will get expected value)

[image]

In second Task we just simply building dynamic sql using that parameter

Also, you can notice that instead of using plain reference to tables like `project.dataset.Table1` and `project.dataset.Mappingtable` - I am using `<var_project_dataset>.Table1` and `<var_project_dataset>.Mappingtable` and parameter `var_project_dataset` is set in parameters panel

After running that workflow ,we get expected result as shown below

[image]

While before execution it was

[image]

Obviously this is simplified example and it will work AS IS only if you have basic column types - no structs and no arrays. Still good news is this approach will easily handle 200 or even more columns you mentioned in your question.

Anyway, I think above example can be a good start for you!

*Disclosure: I am an author and leader of Potens.io Team which is reflected in my profile. I am also Google Developer Expert for Cloud Platform and author of BigQuery Mate Chrome Extension*

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery now supports Dynamic SQL. Building on Mikhail's answer, you can generate his query using:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""
   CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE dataset.Table1 AS 
   SELECT NULL AS %s, NULL AS %s
   FROM (SELECT 1) WHERE FALSE UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM dataset.Table1  
""", 'custColum1', 'custColum2')
```

For more details, see this article:
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-dynamic-sql-in-bigquery-8c04dcc0f0de

Comment: This is excellent thanks. One question: where did you find the functionality of ```format () ```. I've never seen that in any bigquery before

Comment: It's a built-in SQL string function: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#format_string