# Using query parameters in FROM statements

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am running a `DELETE FROM` job on a BigQuery table using the python API. I am trying to make my code as reusable as possible by adding a variable for the table which can be scanned, for example:

```
dml_statement = (
    """
    DELETE FROM `my_project.my_dateset.detail_@market`
    WHERE order_date = @date
    """)
```

This unfortunately returns the error:

> NotFound: 404 Not found: Table
>   my_project:my_dataset.detail_@market was not
>   found in location EU

If I cannot use variables in the `FROM` clause is there any other way I can make the selected table a dynamic input?

I also tried using wildcards and `_TABLE_SUFFIX`, but wildcard selections are not allowed with `DELETE` queries.

Comment: you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55521550/is-there-a-way-in-big-query-to-execute-dynamic-queries-something-like-exec-in

Comment: @JoeTaras I must be missing something, I can't see the solution in this post?

Comment: I suppose yes. In that question, wants to know if exists in Google Big Query a way to replicate the behaviour of dynamic sql query of MS Sql Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with something like:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()  

project = 'YOUR_PROJECT'
dataset = 'YOUR_DATASET'
table = 'YOUR_TABLE'

sql ="""DELETE FROM `{}.{}.{}` WHERE something IS NULL"""
query=sql.format(project,dataset,table)

query_job = client.query(query)
```